Ubuntu 20.04: php lacking permissions to access /var/www/html
I'm trying to write contents to file, however I constantly receive error about lacking permission.
fopen(/var/www/html/files/l.log) Failed to open stream permission denied in /var/www/html/files/file.php

PHP code l use:
$path = __DIR__.'/l.log';
$logfile = fopen($path, "a+") or die();

After checking php and apache processes with:
ps aux | grep apache2
ps aux | grep httpd
ps aux | grep php

I know they both have root and www-data permissions
I tried transferring ownership to www-data or adding permissions for reading and write:
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/files/l.log
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/files/
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/html/files/l.log

But that didn't work.
I also don't have SElinux as mentioned in another post.

Is your PHP code running as part of Apache httpd module or as part of PHP-FPM manager?

... hmm... maybe: Make sure /etc/group has DUMMY:65535: as the very last line.

Upon review of the situation, it appears that your approach regarding the modification of permissions and ownership is appropriate. However, it is advisable to consider several additional factors and implement supplementary measures to effectively resolve the matter at hand. Further investigation and action may be warranted to ensure a comprehensive solution to the issue you are experiencing.
Check Directory Permissions:
Ensure that the directory itself has the correct permissions, not just the file. You need write permissions for the directory where the file is located.
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/files

Alternatively, to make sure you cover all bases, you can change the permissions recursively:
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/files

Check SELinux:
If SELinux is enabled on your system, it might be preventing Apache from writing to the file. You can check the status of SELinux with:
sestatus

If SELinux is enforcing, you can try temporarily setting it to permissive mode to see if that resolves the issue:
sudo setenforce 0

If this resolves the issue, you might need to adjust SELinux policies to allow Apache to write to the file permanently.
